# Inno Setup Compiler как прописать установку доп. ПО?

Tags: qt, windowsinstaller, inno-setup

**Предыстория:** Написал приложение на Qt5.7 MSVC. Собрал все dll-ки с помощью утилиты windeployqt.exe. Сделал инсталлятор используя Inno Setup Compiler. 
И все работало нормально. Пока я не отдал инсталлятор другу. Он установил, но при запуске выбило ошибку: требовало MSVCP140.dll.
Мне объяснили, что для запуска требуется установка пакета vc_redist140.

**Как же прописать, чтобы при установке программы, инсталлятор установил пакет vc_redist140?**

*П.С. Если же существует другой вариант решение проблемы, готов рассмотреть.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так:

```
[Run] 
Filename: {src}\Redist\vcredist_x86.exe; WorkingDir: {src}\Redist; Flags: skipifdoesntexist;
```

Еще так можно сделать:

```
[Tasks]
Name: redist\vc; Description: Microsoft Visual C++; Flags: checkablealone;

[Run]
Filename: {src}\Redist\vcredist_x86.exe; WorkingDir: {src}\Redist; Tasks: Redist\vc; Flags: skipifdoesntexist;
```